# How to open a mp4 file with python?

Tags: python

I was trying to make a script that would play a movie using the default windows application but when I try to run this I get the error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, function found

How should I proceed with this?

```
import os

print 'Push "enter" to play movie'
raw_input()

def filename():
   filename = movie.mp4
   os.system("start " + filename)

open(filename)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open an Excel file with Python to display its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191494/how-to-open-an-excel-file-with-python-to-display-its-content)

Comment: So, I don't know about Windows, but if you have Linux, or a virtual machine, you can leverage ffmpeg, http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you likely have a variable named `movie`, and when you do `filename = movie.mp4` it's setting assigning the `movie`'s function `mp4` to the variable `filename`. In any case, I don't think there's a reason to do this.

```
def play_movie(path):
    from os import startfile
    startfile(path)
```

That's literally all you need for your "Play" function. If I were you, I'd wrap it in a class, something like:

```
class Video(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def play(self):
        from os import startfile
        startfile(self.path)

class Movie_MP4(Video):
    type = "MP4"

movie = Movie_MP4(r"C:\My Documents\My Videos\Heres_a_file.mp4")
if raw_input("Press enter to play, anything else to exit") == '':
    movie.play()
```

Comment: How to detect when the video has finished playing?

Comment: @user2993886 that's true! `os.startfile` is not available on non-Windows OS (per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile))