# Playing MP4 Fullscreen in Python

Tags: python, windows, fullscreen, mp4

I want to play a MP4 Named startup.mp4 fullscreen. I've tried this code :

```
from os import startfile

startfile("C:/Users/idekmauser/desktop/startup.mp4")
```

It does play but not fullscreen how can I make it play fullscreen

Comment: Can you format the question with the code indented, you can do it by highlight the code and pressing ctrl + k.

Comment: This is not how one defines a function with one argument. Also, `C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4` is _not_ a string. Please take [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must Give The Directory As A String Like This 
`"C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4"`
and not this 
`C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4` 
And You Can Run Your MP4 With This Snippet

```
from os import startfile
startfile(r"C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4")
```

For Reference: [[os.startfileDocs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) [[StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313542/how-to-open-a-mp4-file-with-python)

Comment: This error occurs because you are using a normal string as a path. Just put r before that.. and I also edited in the answer too 
startfile(r"C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4")

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by i guess you adding `C:\Users\idekmauser\desktop\startup.mp4` in the begning of the file which is not a string

Your code should look something like this

```
from os import startfile

def play_movie():
    startfile("C:/Users/idekmauser/desktop/startup.mp4")

play_movie()
```

Otherwise to play sounds you can use a Library like playsound

So you start by first installing it

```
pip3 install playsound
```

After that your code should look something like this

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound("C:/Users/idekmauser/desktop/startup.mp4")
```

Comment: Sorry instead of \ you have to use / i forgot to change it. Because otherwise it is going to count as a unicode escape character

Comment: No problems, i changed and it should work now

Comment: You can look at this question maybe that would be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718126/how-to-open-an-application-with-its-window-maximized

Comment: Ypu have to install the library by `pip install win32gui`

Comment: Hahahah no worries we all have been there but no with the command prompt

Comment: Okey that means pip is not installed on your computer, you can follow this tutorial to install it https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows

Comment: To not make this comment section longer you can just hit me up on discord and i will try my best to help you Abodsakka#3667