# Use Python to launch Excel file

Tags: python, excel, macos, launch

when i try 
`os.system("open " + 'myfile.xlsx')`
i get the output `'0'`

similarly, trying
`os.system("start excel.exe myfilepath")`
 gives the result  `32512`

I have imported os and system, and I'm on mac. How can I change this so it does actually launch that excel file? And out of curiosity, what do the numbers it prints out mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are exit codes.  `0` means success, and any other number means failure.  Often the `man` page for a program will tell you a list of the failure codes and what they mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only want to open the excel application you could use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', 'Microsoft Excel'])
```

You can also use os and open a specific file:

```
import os
os.system("open -a 'path/Microsoft Excel.app' 'path/file.xlsx'")
```

If you on other hand want to open an excel file within python and modify it there's a number of packages to use as *xlsxwriter*, *xlutils* and *openpyxl* where the latter is prefered by me.

Another note, if you're on mac the excel application isn't `.exe`

Comment: What does the `a` parameter do? Thank you.

Comment: Just a heads up! xlsxwriter can overwrite your Excel files while OpenPyxl will not. The best way is to copy the file in another folder.

Comment: In mac, `os.system("open -a 'Microsoft Excel' 'path/file.xlsx'")` and this works too: `subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', 'Microsoft Excel','path/file.xlsx'])`

Answer (score 21):

Just these two lines

```
import os
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE file.xlsx")
```

Provided that file.xlsx is in the current directory.

Comment: A tweak: for filenames with embedded blanks enclose the entire parameter with SINGLE quotes and put DOUBLE quotes around the file name 
(e.g. ' start EXCEL.EXE " C:/temp/new file.csv " '. The extra spaces don't hurt and can prevent parameters from being "merged" when the command is run.  BTW on Python 3.x (and possibly 2.x) you should use '/' as the file separator, never "\" - even on Windows.  Python will do the conversion so you don't need to use double backslashes in paths (necessary to prevent the first character from being interpreted as a control character, e.g "\n" = line feed).

Comment: Thanks for the addition user1459519 it was helpfull.

Comment: Worth noting `os.system('start excel.exe file.xlsx')` will open file with same name from your documents folder and `os.system('start "excel.exe" "file.xlsx"')`  (note the extra quotes) will open file from same folder as code is in. Testing this on my end I am not sure y this happens but probably an important distinction.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about Mac OS, but if Windows Operating System is the case and provided the Microsoft Windows is properly installed, then consider using :

```
import os
os.system('start "excel" "C:\\path\\to\\myfile.xlsx"')
```

`double-quotation` is important for `excel` and `C:\\path\\to\\myfile.xlsx` ( where `C` just denotes the letter for the partition within the file system, might be replaced by `D`,`E` ..etc. ), and `single-quotation` is needed for the whole string within the `os.system()`.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10, this works for me:

```
import os
full_path_to_file = "C:\blah\blah\filename.xlsx"
os.system(full_path_to_file)
```

Copy-pasting any full path to a file in the command prompt (or passing it to os.system()) seems to work as long as you have permission to open the file.
I suppose this only works when Excel is selected as default application for the .xlsx extention.

Answer (score 3):

As in: [How to open an Excel file with Python to display its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191494/how-to-open-an-excel-file-with-python-to-display-its-content/21191629)

```py
import os
file = "C:\\Documents\\file.xlsx"
os.startfile(file)
```

It opens the file with the default application.

Comment: NOTE: **Only** available on Windows according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with your most recent downloaded xlsx file, you can use the following:

```py
import glob

import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\\Downloads\\*.xlsx')   *#note the .xlsx extension is needed to retrieve the last downloaded xlsx file.* 

latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

os.system(latest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor improvement that handles spaces and explicitly uses Excel:

```
import os
file = "C:/Documents/file name with spaces.xlsx"
file_with_quotes = '"' + file + '"'
os.system('start "EXCEL.exe" {}'.format(file_with_quotes))
```