# Opening a file in python and tracking the pid of its default application

Tags: python, subprocess, pid, psutil

I need a little help with a program I'm writing. All I need it to do is launch a file in its default program and track the PID of that program (so it can be closed later). I found the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777674/how-do-i-launch-a-file-in-its-default-program-and-then-close-it-when-the-script):

```py
import psutil
import subprocess
import os

file = os.getcwd() + "\\" + input()
open = subprocess.Popen(["start", "/WAIT", file], shell=True)
psutil.Process(open.pid).get_children()[0].kill()
```

This does open the file in the correct program, but it crashes with a

```
IndexError: list index out of range  error on the
```

`psutil.Process(open.pid).get_children()[0].kill()` line.

If anyone has any clue how to acheive what I'm asking, some help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, first, try breaking it down into pieces instead of trying to guess where in that big expression something went wrong. Print out `open.pid`, `Process(open.pid)`, `Process(open.pid).get_children()`, and `Process(open.pid).get_children()[0]` and it should be pretty obvious what the problem is: the `start` process has no children.

Second, `start` doesn't always launch a new process. It runs the `Open` command for a process—which can be a command string, or it can be an OLE thingy or something called via a shell extension DLL, which *may* end up launching a new process, but it could do something else, most commonly opening the file in an existing process for that app. If, say, you give it a `.docx` file, and Word is already open, it asks the existing copy of Word to deal with the file.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* Although in modern versions of Word, I think it's actually `word.exe` that does that, rather than relying on the old OLE mechanisms, in which case that was a bad example…</sub>

And even if it does have to start a new process, it doesn't necessarily do so as a controlled child; it may launch a new detached process, then act the same as if it had found one via OLE. I'm pretty sure that detail isn't documented, but it makes sense (imagine how you'd write `start` if you were them), and you can test it pretty easily:

- Using the `pskill` tool, or `psutil` from within Python, kill the `start` process; the app doesn't even notice.
- Use your favorite third-party command-line tool, or just pop up the process explorer GUI thingy, and see who the parent of the app is.

At any rate, if the app isn't a child of `start`, you can't find it by looking at the children of `start`.

Also, if you look at the Win32 API behind `start` (and Python's [`os.startfile`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/posixmodule.c#l10399), [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), notice that in modern Windows, it doesn't even return a handle to the process.

---

So, how *can* you do this?

Well, as the [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) docs explain:

> You can run nonexecutable files through their file association by typing the name of the file as a command. For more information about creating these associations in a command script by using `assoc` and `ftype` …

So, look at [`assoc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx) and [`ftype`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490912.aspx). You can run `assoc` to get the file type association for your file, then use `ftype` to get the command strings for the `Open` command for that file type, then fill in the `%0` etc. variables yourself, then run it. (If the command isn't a command string, then it's an old OLE-type program, and you can't do this—but then that's exactly the case where you might not be getting a new process in the first place…)

---

Alternatively, you may have noticed that the `ShellExecute` docs say:

> To obtain information about the application that is launched as a result of calling `ShellExecute`, use [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you do that, you can set the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` in the `fMask` flags, and the `hProcess` member will be an `HINSTANCE` for the process (but only if a new process was launched—if a shell extension found an existing process or whatever, you'll still get NULL here, of course). You can then use the normal Win32 process APIs on it, or just get its pid and use it with `psutil`. This is all doable, but probably painful, with `ctypes`; you'd probably want to use the `pywin32` wrappers.

Comment: Wow great explanation! I will do my best to implement your suggestions and hopefully not bother you again. Thanks!