# Python: kill process and close window it opened in (windows)

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, subprocess, kill-process

I'm working on a tool for data entry at my job where it basically takes a report ID number, opens a PDF to that page of that report, allows you to input the information and then saves it.

I'm completely new to instantiating new processes in python; this is the first time that I've really tried to do it. so basically, I have a relevant function:

```
def get_report(id):
    path = report_path(id)
    if not path:
        raise NameError
    page = get_page(path, id)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe", "/A", "page={}".format(page),
                             path])
```

in order to open the report in Adobe Acrobat and be able to input information while the report is still open, I determined that I had to use `multiprocessing`. So, as a result, in the main loop of the program, where it iterates through data and gets the report ID, I have this:

```
for row in rows:
    print 'Opening report for {}'.format(ID)
    arg = ID
    proc = Process(target=get_report, args=(arg,))
    proc.start()

    row[1] = raw_input('Enter the desired value: ')
    rows.updateRow(row)

    while proc.is_alive():
        pass
```

This way, one can enter data without the program hanging on the `subprocess.Popen()` command. However, if it simply continues on to the next record without closing the Acrobat window that pops up, then it won't actually open the next report. Hence the `while proc.is_alive():`, as it gives one a chance to close the window manually. I'd *like* to kill the process immediately after 'enter' is hit and the value entered, so it will go on and just open the next report with even less work. I tried several different things, ways to kill processes through the `pid` using `os.kill()`; I tried killing the subprocess, killing the process itself, killing both of them, and also tried using `subprocess.call()` instead of `Popen()` to see if it made a difference.

It didn't.

What am I missing here? How do I kill the process *and* close the window that it opened in? Is this even possible? Like I said, I have just about 0 experience with processes in python. If I'm doing something horribly wrong, please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried sys.exit(0) ?

Comment: No, I haven't - I guess I misunderstand it; I thought that it would exit the main program as well? I only want to close the window/process spawned as a child of the main process. Will it do that?

Comment: I think i'd misunderstood. You want to close Adobe Reader process?

Comment: Yes, sorry if my post was kind of unclear. I'd like to end the process *and* close the adobe reader window that it's in, while leaving the python program (that's going through data and opening reports) itself running.

Comment: Did you tried _proc.terminate()_ then?

Comment: Won't you will lose the entered data if the user doesn't save and close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill/terminate a subprocess, call `proc.kill()`/`proc.terminate()`. It may leave grandchildren processes running, see [subprocess: deleting child processes in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1230669/4279)

> This way, one can enter data without the program hanging on the subprocess.Popen() command.

1. `Popen()` starts the command. It does not wait for the command to finish. There are `.wait()` method and convenience functions such as `call()`
2. Even if `Popen(command).wait()` returns i.e., if the corresponding external process has exited; it does not necessarily mean that the  document is closed in the general case (the launcher app is done but the main application may persist).

i.e., the first step is to drop unnecessary `multiprocessing.Process` and call `Popen()` in the main process instead.

The second step is to make sure to start an executable that owns the opened document i.e., if it is killed the corresponding document won't stay opened: `AcroRd32.exe` might be already such program (test it: see whether `call([r'..\AcroRd32.exe', ..])` waits for the document to be closed) or  it might have a command-line switch that enables such behavior. See [How do I launch a file in its default program, and then close it when the script finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20777674/4279)

---

> I tried killing the subprocess, killing the process itself, killing both of them, and also tried using subprocess.call() instead of Popen() to see if it made a difference.
>   It didn't.

If `kill()` and `Popen()` behave the same in your case then either you've made a mistake (they don't behave the same: you should [create a minimal standalone code example with a dummy pdf that demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Describe using words: what do you expect to happen (step by step) and what happens instead) or `AcroRd32.exe` is just a launcher app that I've described above (it just opens the document and immediately exits without waiting for the document to be closed).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response. You're right, something in my code before was hanging it up. I removed the part with `multiprocessing` and and just using `Popen`; I saved its `PID` as a global variable in the function that calls it and am using `subprocess` to call `TASKKILL` on that process. It now works exactly as I had hoped. Thanks!

Comment: @carusot42, are you running `taskkill /t` to also kill child processes (at least findable child processes; Windows doesn't maintain a process tree, so orphaned processes occur frequently)? Otherwise why wouldn't `proc.kill()` work? On Windows, it's generally a bad idea to store the PID to kill a process. Process IDs are really just the process handle from the system handle table, so PIDs get reused. `Popen.kill` is safe because it uses the process handle. If you need `taskkill /t`, then first check that it's still alive, i.e. `proc.poll() is None`.